# How reverse linkedlist using recursion works

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, linked-list

I am learning data structure in Python and I've encountered [code](https://repl.it/repls/RosybrownRelievedAmericanwigeon) that I don't understand.
I have a node class

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
```

and linkedlist class

```
class LinkedList():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node()
    ...
    ...
    def reversePrint(self, node=None):
        if node == None:
            node = self.head
        if node.next:
            self.reversePrint(node.next)
        print(node.data)
```

the methods append and delete and find are woking fine
But I can't seem to understand how this method `reverse_print` renders the linkedlist nodes in reverse order i would expect to print only the last node data rather than the whole linkedlist nodes in reverse order.

Here's my [code](https://repl.it/repls/RosybrownRelievedAmericanwigeon)

Comment: It calls `reversePrint` for the next node, and then prints its own data. So it recurses forward, and prints its own data _last_. Everything else is just understanding recursion.

Comment: @khelwood what i understand is `reversePrint` will be called without any printing untill it hits the last element because of the if statement so how `print(node.data)` calls the whole list in reverse order it's supposed to call only the last element value i just can't get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your linked list is

```
Node A: data="alpha"
Node B: data="beta"
Node C: data="gamma"
```

You call `ll.reversePrint()` and `node` gets set to the `head`, which is Node A.

`reversePrint` with node=Node A, checks for the next node (which is Node B), and calls `reversePrint`, passing in Node B.

`-> reversePrint` with node=Node B, checks for the next node (which is Node C), and calls `reversePrint`, passing in Node C.

`-> -> reversePrint` with node=Node C, checks for the next node (there isn't one).

`-> -> reversePrint` with node=Node C prints the node's data: `"gamma"`.

`-> reversePrint` with node=Node B prints the node's data: `"beta"`.

`reversePrint` with node=Node A prints the node's data: `"alpha"`.

The arrows indicate the depth of recursion.

Comment: It clicked with Me! Thanks. Your diagram made it simple to me.

Answer (score 1):

The magic happens in these two lines:

```
if node.next:
        self.reversePrint(node.next)
```

If the node has a successor, it'll call the same method again, all the way up to the end of the list. Then it'll unwind the call stack and, in reverse order, print the data in each node (because `print(node.data)` appears after the recursive call to `reversePrint`). If you switch the `print` statement and the recursive call it'll print it in forward order, which is a bit easier to grasp.

Comment: So every time `self.reversePrint(node.next)` is called the `print(node.data)` stacked in the program memory or something?

Comment: Exactly that, yes :)